# Create multiple custom node add pages

Tags: 7, display-suite

I'm using Display Suite to create custom multiple layouts for content. Is it possible to do something similar to the node/add/mycontent page? I want to be do show/hide and organize fields on the edit and add pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Field group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group). It allows you organize the fields with different transitions.

Comment: Does field group module support multiple different displays, or just adjust the default?

Comment: The module sits on the Manage Fields section section rather than the Manage Display section. So the changes made to the fields will be universal for the all the display modes under a specific content type.